# Php Shell_exec failing to output a file

Tags: php, shell-exec

Hi guys so I'm trying to do something like

```
shell_exec("command"); #this works
shell_exec("ls > outfile");  #the directing to file does not work`
```

[my own command instead of ls]: `ls > outfile`

So I tried running it with `ls` first to see if it works but it doesn't. It can run on the command line but php can't i.e the screen goes blank in browser. I have ensured that the directory has all permissions.

Comment: The user that the web server is running as needs to have write permissions to the `outfile` directory. Also, best to use a full path for `outfile`.

Comment: yes i have given write permission and used the full path for `outfile`

Comment: Does `echo shell_exec("pwd"); exit;` and `echo shell_exec("which ls"); exit;` give the expected results?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
shell_exec("powershell.exe -command "& { ls > outfile }");
```

Comment: It would be better if you could provide an explanation.